# Best possible way to have out put from two tables with high difference in cardinality

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-tuning

I have two tables

```
select col1 , col2 , col3, col4, ........, col20 from ftcm; --TABLE has 470708 ROWS

select val from cspm where product='MARK'; --TABLE has 1 ROW
```

i have to make `col3` as `null` if `col2=val`.

have thought of joining as

```
  select 
    col1 , col2 , decode(col2,val,NULL,col3) col3 , col4, ........, col20
    from ftcm a left outer join ( select val from cspm where product='MARK') b
    on a.col2=b.val;
```

but it seems to be time taking 
Please advise if there is any other way to get it tuned in best way.

Comment: Are your tables properly indexed?

Comment: yes Barranka
Table ftcm on col1
Table cspm on product

Comment: It would be hard to judge w/o `Explain plan` and knowledge of the tables/indexes...etc 

One tiny tip, I think, using `CASE` might give you better performance than `DECODE`.

Comment: Is it significantly slower than fetching just the half million rows from ftcm ? (I know it's not what you want but just to have an idea of what can be done)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this query but if you know that the record from cspm is returning only one value, then you can perhaps try the following query :-

```
select col1, col2, decode(col2,(select val from cspm where product='MARK'),NULL,col3) col3, col4 ... col20 from ftcm
```

Since you are doing an outer join, the above might produce an equivalent output.

Another option which you can explore is to use a parallel hint

```
select /*+ parallel(em,4) */ col1, col2, decode(col2,(select val from cspm where product='MARK'),NULL,col3) col3, col4 ... col20 from ftcm em
```

However, consult with your DBA before using parallel hint at the specified degree (4)

Comment: +1 With scalar subquery caching this should be about as fast as possible.

Comment: Thanks Max 
with below query

Comment: Thanks Max 
with your query 
"select col1, col2, decode(col2,(select val from cspm where product='MARK'),NULL,col3) col3, col4 ... col20 from ftcm"
Cost reduced from 6434 to 439 thnx
I was just needing this query as joining was causing additional cost
Also I observed that whe I tried to create same query before i didn't add Braces to "select val from cspm where product='MARK'"
which caused a missing expression error hence doubted use of query inside Decode
Thanks for enlightening